# Find a permutation $f\in G$ such that $h=fgf^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I've been given two conjugate permutations $h,g \in G=S_{11}$ and have to find another permutation in $G$ such that $h=fgf^{-1}$.

This seems similar to a change of basis for a matrix which I can do easily but I don't know how to proceed with it being permutations instead.

In my case $g=(1,2)(3,4)(5,6,7)(8,9,10,11)$ and $h=(1,11)(4,8,9)(10,5,7,6)(2,3)$

Comment: Do you know the general formula for what conjugation does to a cycle?

Comment: I'm not sure I do. This is an extension question to my course so I don't think it's something we've covered.

Comment: Ok, are you familiar with the fact that conjugation preserves cycle-length? And that conjugating a product yields the product of the conjugates?

Comment: Yeah I figured that they must be conjugate because they both have order 12, how can I use that to find $f$?

Comment: Same order is not enough to ensure being conjugate. They must have the same cycle type. My comment above means that you can split up into what the permutation must do you each cycle (when put in a suitable order).